# How do I remove variables from a list in a method?

Tags: python, list, variables

I'm fairly new to Python and I was wondering how to solve a problem. I'm working on a text-based quiz that identifies symptoms and determines which illness you may be suffering from. I made several lists containing the symptoms. Then I made a method for each illness (repetitive-I know), to cycle through the symptoms and check if the user input matches. If it doesn't, I want the symptom to be removed from a list of possible illnesses. But see, the code can identify if the symptoms match for the first question, but the program still looks for the illness in the list of possibilities even after it's been removed. I've tried using Boolean variables to stop the program from cycling if the illness is not in the possible list. I've tried using a for-loop with the possible list. My most recent attempt made the formerly Boolean variables into strings and checked them that way. Like I said, I'm fairly new to Python, so I'm sorry if this is a simple error. If you can help, please do! This project is due on Friday. Thank you so much!

Here is the code (sorry if this is too long. New to Python-new to the website!):

```
possibles = [ "InfluenzaA", "InfluenzaB", "InfluenzaC", "CommonCold", "Pneumonia", "StrepThroat", "b", "n", "Croup", "EnterovirusD68", "h", "Herpangina", "PinkEye", "Pertussis"]

InfluenzaA = ["Cough", "Runny nose" "Stuffy nose", "Sneezing", "Sorethroat", "Fever", "Headache", "Bodychills", "Fatigue", "Body aches"]

CommonCold = ["Cough", "Runny nose" "Stuffy nose", "Sneezing", "Sorethroat", "Fever", "Headache", "Bodychills", "Fatigue", "Body aches"]

InfluenzaB = ["Cough", "Stuffy nose", "Sore throat", "Fever", "Headache", "Body chills", "Fatigue", "Muscle aches", "Nausea", "Vomiting"]

InfluenzaC = ["Cough", "Rhinorrhea", "Fever", "Headache", "Muscle pain" ]

CommonCold = ["Cough", "Runny nose", "Stuffy nose", "Congestion", "Sneezing","Sore throat", "Fever", "Headache", "Malaise"]

Pneumonia = ["Cough", "Chest pain", "Fever", "Fatigue", "Loss of appetite", "Body pain", "Shortness of breath", "Fast heartbeat"]

StrepThroat = ["Fever", "Headache", "Throat pain", "Loss of appetite", "Nausea", "Vomiting", "White dots", "Red dots", "Inability or diffuculty swallowing"]

Bronchiolitis = ["Cough", "Runny nose", "Stuffy nose", "Fever", "Shortness of breath", "Wheezing", "Ear pain", "Loss of fluids"]

Norovirus = ["Fever", "Abdominal pain", "Malaise", "Muscle pain", "Diarrhea", "Nausea", "Vomiting"]

Croup = ["Cough", "Runny nose", "Stuffy nose", "Shortness of breath", "Wheezing", "Sore throat", "Fever", "Throat pain", "Fatigue"]

EnterovirusD68 = ["Cough", "Runny nose", "Stuffy nose", "Sneezing", "Wheezing", "Fever", "Body aches"]

HandFootandMouthDisease = ["Sore throat", "Fever", "Headache", "Fatigue","Rash", "Drooling"]

Herpangina = ["Sore throat", "Fever", "Headache", "Fatigue", "Loss of appetite", "Inabilty or diffuculty swallowing", "Mouth blisters or ulcers", "Drooling", "Vomiting"]

PinkEye = ["Red eye", "Eye discharge", "Blurred vision", "Light sensitivity"]

Pertussis = ["Cough", "Runny nose", "Stuffy nose", "Fever", "Fatigue", "Vomiting", "Mucus in the throat"]

stinA = "yes"

stinBe = "yes"

stinC = "yes"

stinPer = "yes"

stinHM = "yes"

stinH = "yes"

stinE = "yes"

stinN = "yes"

stinPE = "yes"

stinCr = "yes"

stinCC = "yes"

stinST = "yes"

def cycleInfluenzaA(sy, stinA):

     for i in range(len(InfluenzaA)):

          if InfluenzaA[i].upper() == sy.upper():

                    return

     possibles.remove("InfluenzaA")

     stinA = "no"
```

(The rest are the same format)

```
def ask(bod, stinCC, stinCr, stinE, stinA, stinC, stinBe, stinH, stinN, stinPer, stinPE):

  sy = input("Have you experienced any symptoms relation to your " + bod + "\n")

     if stinCC == "yes":

         cycleCold(sy, stinCC)
```

(The rest are the same format)

```
print("Welcome to this medical database. This is an interactive test to determine what illness a taker may be suffering from. Let's begin.")

ask("chest", stinCC, stinCr, stinE, stinA, stinC, stinBe, stinH, stinN, stinPer, stinPE)

ask("throat", stinCC, stinCr, stinE, stinA, stinC, stinBe, stinH, stinN, stinPer, stinPE)
```

Here is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File "main.py", line 150, in
>
> ask("throat", stinCC, stinCr, stinE, stinA, stinC, stinBe, stinH,
>   stinN, stinPer, stinPE)
>
> File "main.py", line 140, in ask
>
> cycleHerpangina(sy, stinH)
>
> File "main.py", line 100, in cycleHerpangina
>
> possibles.remove("Herpangina")
>
> ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: Please reduce the code in your question to a [_minimal_, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At the moment, there is far too much unrelated material that distracts the essence of your question.

Comment: welcome @Tai_N could probably break up the question into paragraphs as well. Hard to read through so much text in one big block.

Answer (score 0):

print the "possibles" list after execute the first ask(), check whether the "Herpangina" is still exists in the list

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to collect the 'yes's and 'no's for one patient, as they answer whether they have a symptom or not. And keep a tally per disease, you could loop over a disease/symptom dictionary (`symptom_dict`) like this.

```
>>> def interview_patient(patient):
...     for disease in symptom_dict['possibles']:
...         try:
...             for symptom in symptom_dict[disease]:
...                 # answer will be either "yes" or "no".
...                 answer = ask(patient, disease, symptom)
...                 try:
...                     # The patient dict has keys for "yes" and "no".
...                     patient[disease][answer]  += 1
...                     patient[disease]['total'] += 1
...                 except KeyError:
...                     # If the patient didn't have "yes" and "no" keys, 
...                     # create them.
...                     patient[disease] = {'yes': 0, 'no': 0, 'total': 1}
...                     patient[disease][answer]  += 1
...         except KeyError as ke:
...             print(f"There was an error accessing a symptom_dict key: {ke}")
...     return patient
...
```

You could have a function to create a patient who might have a disease and assign a random disease to his 'likelihood' property.

```
>>> def get_patient():
...     return { 'likelihood': random.choice(symptom_dict['possibles']) }
...
```

To model the scenario and test with, we could have a simple function that answers questions like a patient:

```
>>> def ask(patient, disease ,symptom):
...     if patient['likelihood'] == disease:
...         answer = random.choices(['yes', 'no'], [25, 5])[0]
...     else:
...         answer = random.choices(['yes', 'no'], [5, 25])[0]
...     print('have you experienced %-35s %s' % (symptom, answer))
...     return answer
...
```

In the `ask()` function, the answers are weighted, so that when the patient is asked about symptoms related to the disease he likely has, he's more likely to answer yes to each symptom. When asked about symptoms for a disease he doesn't have, he's more likely to answer no.

I reorganized your disease/symptom data into a dictionary for easier access and organization:

```
>>> symptom_dict = {'possibles': ['InfluenzaA', 'InfluenzaB', 'InfluenzaC', 'CommonCold', 'Pneumonia', 'StrepThroat', 'b', 'n', 'Croup', 'EnterovirusD68', 'h', 'Herpangina', 'PinkEye', 'Pertussis'], 'InfluenzaA': ['Cough', 'Runny noseStuffy nose', 'Sneezing', 'Sorethroat', 'Fever', 'Headache', 'Bodychills', 'Fatigue', 'Body aches'], 'CommonCold': ['Cough', 'Runny nose', 'Stuffy nose', 'Congestion', 'Sneezing', 'Sore throat', 'Fever', 'Headache', 'Malaise'], 'InfluenzaB': ['Cough', 'Stuffy nose', 'Sore throat', 'Fever', 'Headache', 'Body chills', 'Fatigue', 'Muscle aches', 'Nausea', 'Vomiting'], 'InfluenzaC': ['Cough', 'Rhinorrhea', 'Fever', 'Headache', 'Muscle pain'], 'Pneumonia': ['Cough', 'Chest pain', 'Fever', 'Fatigue', 'Loss of appetite', 'Body pain', 'Shortness of breath', 'Fast heartbeat'], 'StrepThroat': ['Fever', 'Headache', 'Throat pain', 'Loss of appetite', 'Nausea', 'Vomiting', 'White dots', 'Red dots', 'Inability or diffuculty swallowing'], 'Bronchiolitis': ['Cough', 'Runny nose', 'Stuffy nose', 'Fever', 'Shortness of breath', 'Wheezing', 'Ear pain', 'Loss of fluids'], 'Norovirus': ['Fever', 'Abdominal pain', 'Malaise', 'Muscle pain', 'Diarrhea', 'Nausea', 'Vomiting'], 'Croup': ['Cough', 'Runny nose', 'Stuffy nose', 'Shortness of breath', 'Wheezing', 'Sore throat', 'Fever', 'Throat pain', 'Fatigue'], 'EnterovirusD68': ['Cough', 'Runny nose', 'Stuffy nose', 'Sneezing', 'Wheezing', 'Fever', 'Body aches'], 'HandFootandMouthDisease': ['Sore throat', 'Fever', 'Headache', 'Fatigue', 'Rash', 'Drooling'], 'Herpangina': ['Sore throat', 'Fever', 'Headache', 'Fatigue', 'Loss of appetite', 'Inabilty or diffuculty swallowing', 'Mouth blisters or ulcers', 'Drooling', 'Vomiting'], 'PinkEye': ['Red eye', 'Eye discharge', 'Blurred vision', 'Light sensitivity'], 'Pertussis': ['Cough', 'Runny nose', 'Stuffy nose', 'Fever', 'Fatigue', 'Vomiting', 'Mucus in the throat']}
```

Giving it a run we get output like this:

```
>>> patient = get_patient()
>>>
>>> interview_patient(patient)

have you experienced Cough                               no
have you experienced Runny noseStuffy nose               yes
have you experienced Sneezing                            yes
have you experienced Sorethroat                          yes
have you experienced Fever                               no
have you experienced Headache                            yes
have you experienced Bodychills                          yes
have you experienced Fatigue                             yes
have you experienced Body aches                          no
have you experienced Cough                               yes
<< list continues on and on >>
```

And after all the questions, we have a patient record with tallies for each disease. Based on these counts, you could maybe give them some probability score or something for each disease:

```
>>> patient
{'likelihood': 'StrepThroat', 
'InfluenzaA': {'yes': 4, 'no': 14, 'total': 18}, 
'InfluenzaB': {'yes': 4, 'no': 16, 'total': 20}, 
'InfluenzaC': {'yes': 1, 'no': 9, 'total': 10}, 
'CommonCold': {'yes': 2, 'no': 16, 'total': 18}, 
'Pneumonia': {'yes': 1, 'no': 15, 'total': 16}, 
'StrepThroat': {'yes': 17, 'no': 1, 'total': 18}, 
'Croup': {'yes': 5, 'no': 13, 'total': 18}, 
'EnterovirusD68': {'yes': 2, 'no': 12, 'total': 14}, 
'Herpangina': {'yes': 2, 'no': 16, 'total': 18}, 
'PinkEye': {'yes': 1, 'no': 7, 'total': 8}, 
'Pertussis': {'yes': 3, 'no': 11, 'total': 14}}
```

Threw this together just as a quick example, it might be something you could use.